# $T:\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is linear?

Tags: linear-algebra

$T:\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ such that $T(x)=\overline{x}$.

When we look at $\mathbb{C}$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ it's easy to see that:
$T(x+z)=\overline{x+z}=\overline x + \overline z = T(x)+T(z)$
$T(\lambda x) = \overline{\lambda x} = \lambda \overline{x} = \lambda T(x)$

Now, I understood that $T$ isn't linear if we consider $\mathbb{C}$ a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$.

Why is that? Can you clarify for me the difference?
Thanks

Comment: $T(\lambda x) \neq \lambda T(X)$ if $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ has non zero imaginary part

Comment: $T(-1)=-1$ but $T(-1)=T(ii)=iT(i)=i(-i)=1$

Comment: WHose to say that $\lambda=\bar{\lambda}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose that $T$ is linear with $\mathbb C$ as a $\mathbb C$ vector space.

Then for example:

$$T(i\times i)=iT(i)=1$$

But $$T(i\times i)=T(-1)=-1$$

Contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

Testing linearity on the constant $i$ gives

$$ -i\bar{x} = \overline{ix} = T(ix) = iT(x) = i\bar{x}$$

which is impossible.

Answer (score 2):

If $\Bbb C$ is considered as a vector space over $\Bbb C$ ,$\lambda$ can be complex as well.
So the second property is not satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

Linearity of a transformation is a property of a vector space. To specify a vector space, you must specify a scalar field.

Answer (score 1):

For any linear transformation $T:V\to V$, the set of $x$ such that $Tx=x$ is a subspace of $V$. But for $V=\mathbb C$ and $T=$ conjugation, this set is $\mathbb R$, which is not a $\mathbb C$-subspace of $\mathbb C$. Hence, conjugation is not a $\mathbb C$-linear transformation.